# Google Maps API | How to change map style (retro to night mode) when it's dark outside (time-dependant)?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on a website project and for some reason, my client wants the embedded map to change style when it's dark outside.
(Styles: retro and night mode)

I just implemented the retro style for the map using the exact same code base
I found at this [GOOGLE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple) website.

The styles for the night mode one can look up [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-array).

My question:
How can I toogle between those two map styles regarding a specific time that I can either set myself (i.e. 8pm) or how can one change the style depending on the sunrise/sunset in her or his specific time-zone?

I didn't find any information on this topic in my online research and also not on google's developer sites.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a Google Maps issue. You just need to call `map.setMapTypeId` with the correct id when the condition is met.

e.g.

```
if(your_condition) {
  map.setMapTypeId(my_custom_id);
}
```

Note that the condition will be only checked once in this case (so if the user does not refresh the page, he won't see any change - use `setInterval` to check the condition every x seconds).
To help you deal with dates, the [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) library is very useful (and knows how to deal with timezones too).

If you want to calculate sunrise/sunset time, there are libraries for that: https://github.com/mourner/suncalc

Comment: Thank you ValLeNain. I'll be working through your suggestions!